# Angular detect no user action for 1 minute

Tags: angularjs

I want to set a timer in the controller that if the user does not click any button or input any field for 1 minute, the page goes to login page.

any idea how to do that?

Comment: $timeout does the work for u ?

Comment: @SasankSunkavalli, how to detect there is no user activity? if there is user activity, need to reset timer and start timer again

Comment: $timeout(function() {
  if($scope.userActivity == false) {
     // call the  same timeout again
  }
},60000);

Comment: This will do it for u

Answer (score 3):

[ng-idle](http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/)  is a module for detecting and responding to idle users.

Generally, it shows a modal when it detects inactivity and after a period of time if the user is still idle, it executes action (e.g: logout)

There is an Angular 2 version too: [ng-idle2](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle)

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  var lastDigestRun = new Date();
  $rootScope.$watch(function detectIdle() {
    var now = new Date();
    if (now - lastDigestRun > 1*60*60) {
       // login here, etc
    }
    lastDigestRun = now;
  });
});
```

Comment: how do you detect there is no user action and if there is any user action, I need to reset the timer and start the timer again

Comment: @gotnull how does detectIdle() execute exactly after 1 min

Comment: Interesting idea. Haven't thought of this as one way to detect user activity.
But one thing though, the app could have some parts that invoke a digest cycle even without any user interactions, right? For example, `$timeout` ticks trigger a digest cycle.